# Is MYSQL good for desktop applications

Tags: java, mysql, windows, desktop

i hope to develop software using java for my shop requirements like product handling, purchase handling, invoice handling. is there any problem when using MYSQL as a database of desktop applications?
and is that MYSQL only tuned for Web Applications?

Thank you

Comment: You can use it. There is noting like only for web application.

Comment: Are you asking it to use mysql as a application local storage medium?

Comment: yes thavan , its to store data locally..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. It is open source, easy to start using, light, and suitable for your needs. No, MySQL is not only for web applications. There are many applications of the product and tool domain which are using it.

Comment: Ya sqlLite would be a good option if you think databse is small.

Answer (score 1):

If your database is small and simply I'd recommend using SQLite. MySQL will work too but it's more difficult to install and configure it on user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as database tuned for web applications, the database choice depends on the application requirements.
Mysql should work just fine in most cases, although if you need something quicker to use you can use SqlLite.